# Read Jena OntModel with Dependencies

Tags: java, owl, jena

I'm new to the concept of ontology and Jena, so I'm not sure I'm phrasing this correctly..

I need to read a series of connected owl files (by namespace dependencies?) into an in memory Jena model (OntModel?) so inference can be run.  How do I do this?  Does the order of the files matter?  Do I need to call a specific method to "run the inference engine"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what I did.  It seems to work

```
    OntModel model = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel();
    for (OwlFile referencedOntology: referencedOntologyList) {
        model.getDocumentManager().addAltEntry( referencedOntology.getNamespace(), referencedOntology.getURI());
    }
    model.read(ontology.getURI());
```

The `OwlFile` object contains the URI to the ontology file as well as its namespace.

`referencedOntologyList` contains a list of referenced `OwlFile`s

`ontology` is the `OwlFile` containing the main ontology.